# Sessions, Window stations and Desktops

Tags: windows

Sessions, Window Stations and Desktops.

> A session consists of all process and
>   other system objects that represent a
>   single user's logon session. Sessions
>   contain Window Stations and Window
>   Stations contain desktops.

The above is from http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx

(Similar articles say the same thing, e.g. blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx and blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx)

I've always understood Sessions and logon sessions to be one and the same thing.

However, reading p. 474, Russinovich and Solomon, Windows Internals, 5th edition, it says (penultimate paragraph):

> The CreateProcessWithLogon function
>   also creates a token by creating a new
>   logon session with an initial process,
>   which is how the Runas command
>   launches processes under alternative
>   tokens.

So Runas creates a new logon session. If we use Runas to run Notepad under a different user's credentials we see it appear on the desktop. So Notepad is running on the same desktop as everything else. (This is, as far as I understand it, the default desktop in Window Station Winsta0; the interactive window station.) So what we have now are *two* logon sessions associated with the same Session (the thing that contains window stations). So Sessions and logon sessions would not appear to be one and the same.

Can anybody confirm this please?

Confused

Comment: The web page below gives an illustrated explanation of sessions, window stations and desktop:
http://securityinternals.blogspot.ae/2014/01/on-sesssion-windows-and-desktops.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are indeed two types of sessions here.  Here's my understanding of how they work.

1. A [logon session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378338(v=vs.85).aspx)<sub><sup>[[2](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/WhatIsALogonSession.html)]</sup></sub> is managed by the [Local Security Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378326(v=vs.85).aspx)<sub><sup>[[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service)]</sup></sub>, and manages the scope of a user logon.  These are created primarily by the [winlogon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winlogon) process, but also secondarily by API functions such as [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx), [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx), and [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx), or by applications that use these functions, such as the [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command.

   A logon session isn't tied to any specific [Object Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724826(v=vs.85).aspx)<sub><sup>[[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows))]</sup></sub> concepts as [window stations and desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681928(v=VS.85).aspx).  It's basically just a block of information containing the logon SID and some cached security information about the account.  This block of information, this logon session, is what an [access token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_token) points to.
2. The other type of session is sometimes called a Terminal Services session, Terminal Server session, [Remote Desktop session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383496(v=vs.85).aspx), logon session (as confusing as that is), user logon session, or user session.  Usually, though, it's just called a "session", without further qualification.

   This is the type of session that you'll usually hear about, and is what [window stations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx) belong to.  This type of session [came about](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-session.html) to support multiple interactive GUI logons, as provided by Terminal Services (now known as [Remote Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services)), and is now also used to support [Fast User Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_user_switching).  Sessions provide the necessary isolation between the Object Manager objects associated with each user logon.

I don't spend much time messing with all this stuff, so I'm a little fuzzy on some of the details, but I think this is a pretty fair representation of the overall picture.  I hope it clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks! Having read over the weekend chapter 3 of Windows Internals, and experimented with Sysinternals tools like logonsessions what you describe fits the mental picture I have built up over what is going on. It's just a pity most M$ technical docs fail to make the distinction between the two animals. Thx particularly for the reference to [this article](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-session.html). Reading this just now further helped to crystallize everything. Thx again!

Comment: Thanks again. I have just been wasting an entire morning only to discover that the docs are each using the word "session" in a different way. Been trying to create a console session using LogonUser in vain, the function suceeds but the token returned is for an LSA session not a interactive session at all.

Comment: Window Stations and Terminal Services are not conceptually tied to each other. In fact there used to be a time when TS weren't an integral part of Windows and yet we had Desktops and Window Stations.

Comment: Sessions were in the original design, but as subsystem sessions (OS/2, POSIX) tied together by a logon session. The latter was supposed to have its own object directory. Instead the Windows subsystem put everything in the global `\BaseNamedObjects` and `\DosDevices`. Then NT 4 moved the window manager to the kernel via win32k.sys, so implementing Hydra (Terminal Services) required virtualizing win32k's state and adding a `\Sessions\[SESSION_ID]` directory for local named objects. Now, smss.exe respawns in a new session to run csrss.exe and winlogon.exe, leaving them orphaned when it exits.

Comment: With XP, Windows came back to the idea of a logon session directory, but only for device links (e.g. mapped drives) created in `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\[LOGON_SESSION_ID]`. They also renamed the global directory as `\GLOBAL??` (global what?). Personally, I would have made `\Sessions\[SESSION_ID]\DosDevices` a symlink to a `\LogonSessions` directory. In it, SYSTEM's logon session (`00000000-000003e7`) would link to the global `\DosDevices`. Other logon sessions would use `[LOGON_SESSION_ID]`. Anyway, native code should use `\??` to let the object manager select the right directory.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, nowadays a `WindowStation` is logically contained by a `Session`. The first field of the undocumented `WINSTATION_OBJECT` is the session ID, and the named object path is in `\Sessions\[SESSION_ID]\Windows\WindowStations`. win32k.sys data in the kernel is virtualized in kernel session space, so `WindowStation` and `Desktop` objects are deeply connected to their associated `Session`.

Comment: @eryksun The Session you refer to is a Logon Session. That's still conceptually different from a TS session to my knowledge. Otherwise please provide sources, my knowledge may of course be outdated.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, logon sessions have 64-bit IDs from `NtAllocateLocallyUniqueId`, with some hard-coded such as 999 (0x3e7) for the SYSTEM logon. The `\Sessions` directory is for NT sessions, which have 32-bit IDs starting at 0 and incremented sequentially. That's how they were always numbered since NT 3.1, but before Hydra, they were created by the session manager when requested over its LPC `\SmApiPort` and used only for subsystem sessions. There wasn't a session space in the kernel or a `\Sessions` object directory used by the object manager to virtualize `\BaseNamedObjects` and `\Windows`.

Comment: @eryksun Wait, so what you are saying is 1.) NT sessions == TS sessions or 2.) NT sessions are a third type of session?

Comment: @0xC0000022L, Terminal Services (Hydra) was a substantial enhancement to NT sessions to support multiple instances of the Windows subsystem (i.e. `\Windows`, `\BaseNamedObjects`, csrss.exe, winlogon.exe, and kernel session space since a lot of the window manager code was moved to the kernel via win32k.sys in NT 4). Interestingly, it originally copied the system `\DosDevices` to each NT session's `DosDevices` without any dynamic link between them, which was wrong since they need to be linked and they need to be instanced per *logon session*, not NT session. They fixed this in NT 5.1 (XP).

Comment: @eryksun: thanks. In that case I am glad. Otherwise I would have had to do a lot of reading.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, Microsoft can't make up its mind on the name. To me, they're an integral part of the native OS design, and they'll always be NT sessions; they've just evolved over time. See the NT design workbook "Windows NT Session Management and Control" written by Mark Lucovsky (last revised in Jan 1990).