# Getting TS session ID that user is using from LUID

Tags: winapi, windows-services, windows-xp, terminal-services

I am connecting to an XP computer on a domain using remote desktop (no user is or was connected since last restart), and I can see that the applications I am using (like explorer.exe) belongs to TS session ID 0.

In the same time I am getting information using the function `LsaGetLogonSessionData()` in a Windows service I am running, and according to the information I get from that function, my TS session ID is 2 (for example) and **NOT** 0.

How can I tell in my Windows service that my login is using explorer.exe at TS session 0 if the function tells me that it is on TS session 2 ?!

I must admit that these Windows session got me REALLY confused!

---

I'll try to rephrase the question:
How do I know on which TS session ID a LUID is using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be due to [logon session vs RDP session mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686897/sessions-window-stations-and-desktops).  Try ProcessIdToSessionId  instead.

Comment: Hey John! Thanks for your answer! :-)
ProcessIdToSessionId() doesn't solve my problem.
My goal is to know which "desktop" gets which LUID, or in other words, on which explorer.exe a given LUID is using.

Comment: The explorer.exe shell process does not have to be the same user as the "desktop" as you call it.